# Django static files not serving in DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Trying to create a Profile View in the app I just started. I can't seem to figure out this simple issue I'm having though. When I load my index page or any other page that doesn't have a pk, everything loads correctly. However, whenever I attempt to load a page that has something like /profile/1/ in the url, the staticfiles won't load. I keep getting a 404. Please help! My code is rather long already, but I'll break it down. I'll add my settings, urls, and views, and profile page. I can't think of anything else that would be needed at this time.

**Settings.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dispatch/templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dispatch/static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dispatch/media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**URLS.py at Project level**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('dispatch.urls', namespace='dispatch')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**URLS.py at App Level:**

```
# SET THE NAMESPACE!
app_name = 'dispatch'

# Be careful setting the name to just /login use userlogin instead!
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'profile_detail'
    model = models.UserProfile
    template_name = 'pages/profile.html'
```

**pages/profile.html**

```
{% extends 'lib/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block page_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendors/css/extensions/pace.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/pages/users.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <div align="right">

    <p>{{ profile_detail.user }}</p>
    <p>{{ profile_detail.zipcode }}</p>
    <img src="{{ profile_detail.profile_image }}" alt="Profile Image">

 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Error from manage.py** Note the /profile/1/ in the path

```
[12/Jun/2017 20:40:04] "GET /profile/1/static/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2570
[12/Jun/2017 20:40:04] "GET /media/CACHE/images/profile_images/20170612_110531/7d87ed0f89df89bff1d122fbf82bb83d.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /profile/1/profile_images/20170612_110531.jpg
[12/Jun/2017 20:40:04] "GET /profile/1/profile_images/20170612_110531.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2525
```

Comment: I think you are missing the "STATIC_ROOT" like `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')`

Comment: Tried that as well, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you post the content of the template lib/base.html? As that specific 404 error copied above references `vertical-menu.css`, which is not referenced in the pages/profile.html template that you posted. My guess is that your 404 is in the base template and not the code above, but I have no way of verifying.

Comment: found issue. It was an accidental period before the static tag in my base.html file.